# find method ArgumentError "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In rails console..

`Physician.find(1285849521)` results in

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `new'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `substitute_at'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:989:in `block in create_binds'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:987:in `each'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:987:in `each_with_index'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:987:in `create_binds'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:962:in `build_where'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:586:in `where!'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:576:in `where'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:10:in `where'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/core.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in find'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/statement_cache.rb:80:in `call'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/statement_cache.rb:80:in `create'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/core.rb:149:in `block in find'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mutex_m.rb:73:in `synchronize'
... 13 levels...
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `block in load'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tim/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

and of course..

`Physician.find()` results in "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Physician without an ID"

My physician.rb is

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "t_phys"
    self.primary_key = "sln"
end
```

I'm using a legacy postgres db, the table t_phys has a natural key called sln, which is a 10 digit integer. There is a physician in the db with sln 1285849521 (the integer in the find method above), which I know because Physician.all() works properly and that's the first record that is displayed.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the find method to work properly? I'm just getting started with rails again, probably a newbie mistake somewhere. Appreciate the help!

For more detail, when I got to localhost:3000/physicians/1285849521, the page renders:

```
ArgumentError in PhysiciansController#show

Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #160):                

159        def substitute_at(column, index)
160          Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new "$#{index + 1}"
161        end
162
163        def exec_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [])
```

I can provide the full stack trace if necessary.

Comment: Could be a bug in ActiveRecord 4.2 beta 4. Have you tried going forward (looks like there's a Rails 4.2 rc2) or backward to something more stable like Rails 4.1?

Comment: I updated to 4.2 rc2 and now have a different, more promising "Couldn't find Physician with 'sln'=1285849521" error. Working on debugging it now, thanks!

Comment: @ToddAgulnick: You should make this an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should work, but I'm wondering if the custom primary key is still messing with `find`.

Maybe this background will help confirm one way or the other:

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Comment: Yeah I need to read up on this more anyway, thanks for the linking, going through it now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Todd Agulnick's comment above, I updated to Rails 4.2 rc2 and the error went away. I encountered a new error, which I resolved and is outside the scope of this question. Thanks Todd!

Comment: You're welcome. I feel that there's an underlying truism at work here, something along the lines of "the elusive problems always hide where you're not looking." In this case, since you are newly returned to Rails you naturally figured the problem was your mistake. So of course it was a problem with Rails. Glad to hear you got it working.